# ANY operator equivalent in SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Is there `ANY` operator equivalent in SQLite? SQLite gives an error near ANY operator. Is there any other way to do this in SQlite? I want to select a set of records which does not equal to any of the records in another set.

For an example,

```
SELECT EventLogId from EventLog Where EventLog <> ANY (SELECT EventLogId FROM Table2)
```

Comment: `Where EventLog not in ( select ...`

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168929/sqlite-syntax-for-all

Comment: @Abhik Correct solution. Can you post this as the answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not in`

```
Where EventLog not in ( select ..
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT EventLogId 
FROM EventLog 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM Table2 
                 WHERE Table2.EventLogId = EventLog.EventLog)
```